# PHP Shebang not working

Tags: php, shell, shebang

NOTE: This question has been solved. It is a duplicate of [shebang line not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8027447/shebang-line-not-working)

---

This is what I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
echo "starting";
```

The file is executable "-rwxr-xr-x"

I call the file with its complete path

```
/var/projects/user-backup.php
```

But I only get the error-message ": No such file or directory"

Calling the script with

```
php /var/projects/user-backup.php
```

results in the String "Starting..." being displayed as expected.

Even when I try to

```
 /usr/bin/env php /var/projects/user-backup.php
```

everything works out fine, the String "starting..." is displayed as expected.

Where am I going wrong?

EDIT1:
Using shebang like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
```

results in the Error-message "^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory"
although there definitely is a /usr/bin/php (/usr/bin/php -> /etc/alternatives/php , and  /etc/alternatives/php -> /usr/bin/php5)

Comment: Looks ok. What happens if you run `/usr/bin/env php` on the commandline?

Comment: /usr/bin/env php /var/projects/user-backup.php works fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I've got it (due to question ***@EDIT1***).

A couple of words about [[Wikipedia]: Newline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) (*EOLN*s):

- *Win*: "***\r\n***" ("***\x0D\x0A***", *CR* + *LF*)
- *Nix*:

  - *Linux*: "***\n***" ("***\x0A***", *LF*)
  - *OSX*: "***\r***" ("***\x0D***", *CR*)

Your *.php* file has *Win* style *EOLN*s (at least the one on the *shebang* line), while some *Nix* interpreters don't like *CR*, and this is the case here.

As a side note, *Nano* (or any decent editor, as a matter of fact) figures out the line endings in a file when editing it, and when adding new lines, their *EOLN*s are consistent with the existing ones.

To make things work, convert your file *EOLN*s to *Nix* (*Linux*) style:

```
dos2unix /var/projects/user-backup.php
```

Might want to also read [[SO]: Flask CLI throws 'OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error' when run through docker-compose (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55272071/4788546).

Comment: this feels like a nonsensical answer but i tried it anyways and it fix my issues. thanks.

Comment: @AngelS.Moreno: Why does this feel nonsensical? It identified and solved the problem.

Comment: sorry, I meant the solution seemed weird, not the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Put `/usr/bin/php` into the file `/etc/shells`.

Comment: tried that, still no luck...

Answer (score 0):

It was the line endings!! Although I used "nano" to edit the file in a putty-window, I still got the windows-line-endings.

After using "dos2unix" to convert all line-endings, things worked out!

Compare answer here in this question:
[shebang line not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8027447/shebang-line-not-working)