# Flask CLI throws 'OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error' when run through docker-compose

Tags: python, windows, docker, flask, docker-compose

I'm running a Flask application with a [Custom Script](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/cli/#custom-scripts). Or trying to, anyway.

I'm on Windows 10 and the application ought to run in a linux Docker container with the command:

```
docker-compose up api
```

Docker-compose is `version 1.23.2`. In the dockerfile, the `api` service runs via the command:

```
command: python manage.py run --host "0.0.0.0" --with-threads
```

As it tries to start up, I see the exception

```
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: '/api/manage.py'
```

I initially thought this would be the Dreaded Windows Line Endings, come for me once more, but running `dos2unix` on all my source files has not resolved the problem.

How can I avoid this error?

---

**manage.py**

```py
    import click
    from flask.cli import FlaskGroup

    from my_app_api import create_app


    def create_my_app(info):
        return create_app()


    @click.group(cls=FlaskGroup, create_app=create_my_app)
    def cli():
        pass


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        cli()
```

**Full traceback**

```
api_1          | Traceback (most recent call last):
api_1          |   File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
api_1          |     cli()
api_1          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 764, in __call__
api_1          |     return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
api_1          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 380, in main
api_1          |     return AppGroup.main(self, *args, **kwargs)
api_1          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 717, in main
api_1          |     rv = self.invoke(ctx)
api_1          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1137, in invoke
api_1          |     return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
api_1          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 956, in invoke
api_1          |     return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
api_1          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 555, in invoke
api_1          |     return callback(*args, **kwargs)
api_1          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 64, in new_func
api_1          |     return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
api_1          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 555, in invoke
api_1          |     return callback(*args, **kwargs)
api_1          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 438, in run_command
api_1          |     use_debugger=debugger, threaded=with_threads)
api_1          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 988, in run_simple
api_1          |     run_with_reloader(inner, extra_files, reloader_interval, reloader_type)
api_1          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/_reloader.py", line 332, in run_with_reloader
api_1          |     sys.exit(reloader.restart_with_reloader())
api_1          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/_reloader.py", line 176, in restart_with_reloader
api_1          |     exit_code = subprocess.call(args, env=new_environ, close_fds=False)
api_1          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 287, in call
api_1          |     with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
api_1          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 729, in __init__
api_1          |     restore_signals, start_new_session)
api_1          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1364, in _execute_child
api_1          |     raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
api_1          | OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: '/api/manage.py'
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Looks like your *api/manage.py* doesn't have a ***shebang*** ([[Wikipedia]: Shebang (Unix)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))), so the default (current) command processor (a *shell* - typically *bash*) is attempting to run it, which (obviously) fails.

To correct the problem, add a *shebang* (at the beginning of the file, making sure that your editor adds the *Nix* style line ending (***\n***, ***0x0A***, ***LF***)):

- Default *Python* installation:

  ```bash
  #!/usr/bin/env python
  ```

  - Variant (specify *Python 3* explicitly):

    ```bash
    #!/usr/bin/env python3
    ```
- Custom *Python* installation:

  ```bash
  #!/full/path/to/your/custom/python/executable
  ```

Note that you also need *exec* permissions on the file (`chmod +x api/manage.py`).

Example:

> ```
> [cfati@cfati-5510-0:/cygdrive/e/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q055271912]> ~/sopr.sh
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [064bit prompt]> ls
> code00.py  code01.py
> [064bit prompt]>
> [064bit prompt]> cat code00.py
> print("This is:", __file__)
>
> [064bit prompt]> python3 -c "import os, subprocess;subprocess.Popen(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), \"code00.py\")).communicate()"
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
>     restore_signals, start_new_session)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1344, in _execute_child
>     raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
> OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: '/cygdrive/e/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q055271912/code00.py'
> [064bit prompt]>
> [064bit prompt]> cat code01.py
> #!/usr/bin/env python3
>
> print("This is:", __file__)
>
> [064bit prompt]> python3 -c "import os, subprocess;subprocess.Popen(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), \"code01.py\")).communicate()"
> This is: /cygdrive/e/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q055271912/code01.py
> ```

Another way would be to run the interpreter followed by the file name, but I don't know how to do it from *Flask* - actually that would require patching *Werkzeug* (*_reloader.py*: *_get_args_for_reloading*), but that would be just a lame workaround (*gainarie*) - see below.

---

#### Update *#0*

Looking at @AxelGrytt's answer, it turns out it's a known issue: [[GitHub]: pallets/werkzeug - 0.15.0 causes OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: in Docker for Windows](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/issues/1482) (hmm, submitted in the same day as this question (and 2 days after the release) :) ).

So, what I have stated above is correct, but it is worth mentioning that there is another way of fixing it: removing the *exec* permission for the file:

```bash
chmod -x api/manage.py
```

According to *Werkzeug* authors, from now on, **this is desired behavior** (also applies to *v**0.15.2***):

- A file **with** *exec* permission set, **should** also have a *shebang*
- A file **without** a *shebang*, **shouldn't** have the *exec* permission set

Comment: That fixed it! It worked *sans* shebang for my coworkers running on OSX, and I still haven't the faintest idea why. The Docker command is `python manage.py run --host "0.0.0.0" --with-threads`, so I feel like it *ought* to be running through the Python interpreter, but I guess it wasn't?

Comment: Maybe *OSX* has another way of associating files and apps (similar to *Win*)? Or they have some env var or *Flask* property set? But I can only guess without further info.

Comment: Or it could be that your coworkers have an older *Werkzeug* version :)

Answer (score 29):

This is a new behavior in Werkzeug 0.15. Downgrading to Werkzeug 0.14.1 may work, but 0.14 is no longer supported, so you will be better off correcting the issue with your file as described in the other answers.

Comment: Do you have more details? Could you share an official *URL* to the bug?

Comment: I didn't specify a version for `Werkzeug` (the latest is `0.15.4` at my development process) in the `requirements.txt` file. When I use `Werkzeug==0.14.1` at the `requirements.txt` then the problem is gone. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 11):

If you disable debug mode (don't pass `debug=True` or set `FLASK_DEBUG=0`), the reloader will not be used and so this issue will not happen. The tradeoff is that you no longer have the reloader.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    connexion_app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=constants.API_PORT, debug=True)
```

It is preferrable to fix this by ensuring files marked as executable have an interpreter line, like `#!/usr/bin/env python3` (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/55272071).

Answer (score 2):

The answer of @CristiFati worked for me with 1 additional step:

I also had to correct the EOL from `\r\n` to `\n`.

---

Sorry I don't have enough points to add a comment and have to open a new answer...

Comment: ***\_reloader.py* has *Nix* style *EOLN*s**, so the one that you had to replace was (silently) introduced by your editor, when you added the shebang. Note: a decent editor would detect line endings in an existing file, and be consistent with them when adding new ones.

Answer (score 1):

Werkzeug==0.15.4  has this question。

```
pip install --user Werkzeug==0.16
```