# OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error - python

Tags: python, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Whenever I run my program using the command python app.py on Ubuntu on Windows it displays this entire message. Seems to me that it runs for a bit then crashes. I honestly have no clue where in my code the error is at, doesn't seem to show on the picture either. All it shows is the `OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error`. Can someone please explain why I am getting this error? This is not a duplicate thread since I am not using docker and that error is different.

[image]

---

[image]

The code I am using:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session, logging, url_for, redirect, flash
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker


from passlib.hash import sha256_crypt
```

Comment: What if you just run 'python'?  This looks like it might have nothing to do with your program.

Comment: @Steve I tried that out just now and it just gives me the GCC for it. Please see the modified post with the image url named"Just running 'python'.

Comment: Do not share screenshots of code or text output. Instead, copy/paste the code itself. You also should supply more information about the issue: what environment is it running in, what library versions you are using, what have you tried so far to fix it...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flask CLI throws 'OSError: \[Errno 8\] Exec format error' when run through docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55271912/flask-cli-throws-oserror-errno-8-exec-format-error-when-run-through-docker)

Comment: It is not a duplicate. I have the tag ubuntu-18.04, because I am using that environment. Like I said, I do not know where in my program I am getting the error. If I did, I would be more than happy to provide that snippet. @swalladge

Comment: @beloas, actually glad that python is running OK for you.  So now, I'd try running the simplest possible python program.  Since you're getting some sort of "format error", I'd now want to rule out that it's something about your input file.

Comment: That "duplicate answer" actually makes no sense at all to me.  It's talking about a "shebang" at the top of the file, but that shouldn't be relevant if you're running python explicitly and treating your file as a parameter you're passing to Python.  I don't get that one at all.  In case there's something I'm missing about how you're running your app, you might want to make sure you've got a proper shebang at the top of your file.  Again, I don't think that matters.  But something's wrong, so who knows.

Comment: ...maybe it is something like that, because this really seems to have nothing to do with Python itself.  I don't think it's getting as far as starting to read and run your code.  That's just not what that error says to me.  That's not an error from Python itself.

Comment: Wait a minute.  I just re-read your question, and see "run my program using the command python app.py on Ubuntu on Windows ".  What does that mean?  How exactly are you running this?  How are both Ubuntu and Windows involved?

Comment: @Steve So my operating systems is Windows 10. I downloaded Ubuntu for Windows 10, so whenever I am on Ubuntu I go into the directory where my python file is located and I simply type `python app.py` which executes the program according to others stating that's how you would run your program. I will go ahead and create a simple program and run that same command and see if I get the same issue.

Comment: @Steve I created a simple hello world python file and ran the same command `python basic.py` just like I did for `python app.py` and it displayed hello world. Do you think its a header that I am missing that is causing that issue?

Comment: Could be.  You should make sure that the first line of each file is the same.  If it is, I'd say that it also might be some funny encoding of the file.  Like maybe the file is some strange unicode format or something.  hard to know.  How about copying all of your code except the first line, if that matters, from the old file to the new file? - in general, divide an conquer.  Just keep working with the two files until you figure out what's different about them.  If it's just the file itself, that would be strange, but you could then just delete the original file and rename the new one.

Comment: @Steve Do you think its something with the imports? Please see the beginning snippet that I provided on the original post.

Comment: @beloas, I feel like a complete idiot. I thought I'd looked at both your screenshots, but I just saw the Flask output and stack trace for the first time. We've been speaking two different languages here I fear. I thought you were running this at the command prompt and ONLY getting that error. I didn't realize that this is a Flask app, and that you were getting all that valuable output. So this is completely different. I'm sorry for wasting your time. I don't know how anything I've said could have been all that helpful. – Steve 5 mins ago     Delete

Comment: I do know this environment.  We're running two Flask apps that I wrote.  But I gotta rethink this.  If you still need my help tomorrow, I'd be happy to keep looking at this.  Signing off for tonight.

Comment: What is your Windows build number? See [this link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/13443/windows-which-operating-system) if you are unsure on how to get the build number.

Comment: @Steve No worries, I appreciate all the help! I am still trying to figure out why I am getting that error but no luck.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid The OS Build is 17134.648, why?

Comment: The latest build is [18342](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/release-notes#build-18342) try updating to see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid My laptop doesn't have that update.

Answer (score 14):

I encountered the same problem and this is how i solved it:

I uninstalled the werkzeug version that was initially installed

```
pip uninstall werkzeug
```

Then i re-installed werkzeug 0.14.1 version. That solved it for me.

```
pip install --upgrade werkzeug==0.14.1
```

Here's a link on how to [upgrade/downgrade werkzeug](https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/python/python-pip-downgrade-package/)

Comment: Please get the commands from the url and put it on your answer as it will improve its quality.

Comment: Thank you so much, mine was 0.15.2 and working well after downgrade to 0.14.1

Answer (score 1):

Please check: [Flask CLI throws 'OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error' when run through docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55271912/flask-cli-throws-oserror-errno-8-exec-format-error-when-run-through-docker)

"There is a bug with werkzeug 0.15.1 and docker. Downgrading it to werkzeug==0.14.1 worked for me."

Also for me...