# Exec format Error while running dockerised Hello world python example

Tags: python, docker, flask

I am trying to learn docker from basics. In their official docs, they have demonstrated a simple Hello world Python app. But if i try the same on a Windows host I'm getting the following exception.  My hello world code

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=int("5000"), debug=True)
```

and my docker file:

```
FROM python:alpine3.7
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
CMD python ./index.py
```

The requirement.txt file just contains the library name(flask) to be installed.

and the error im getting while running the dockerised image is

[image: Console output from Windows]

I am completely new to both docker and python. So please help me out...Thanks in advance

Comment: Building and running your code using Docker on Linux does not have an error.  I suspect the issue is something to do with a windows/linux interaction.

Comment: can you copy paste your console output in question

Comment: Have you checked the answers [in this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55271912/flask-cli-throws-oserror-errno-8-exec-format-error-when-run-through-docker)

Comment: Thanks arsho adding shebang fixed the issue...thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd seen this pattern before, so I was pretty sure what the error message meant, but in this case I could not think why.  What seems to be going on is that Flask restarts itself, but where the original execution was started with `python ./index.py`, the restart is doing `/app/index.py`.  It is trying to treat what was originally the first input parameter to `python`, the Python file to execute, like it is directly executable.  The error is saying that it is not.  If you put a shebang line, like `#!/usr/bin/env python` at the top of this file, and make it executable, it might start working for you.  But you shouldn't have to do that.  The setup here should work fine.

So I Googled, and this seems like a known problem with the combination of **werkzeug** (a library used by Flask), **Docker**, and **Windows**:

https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/issues/1482

Since I'm not on Windows, I'll leave it to the OP or someone else to take it from here.

Comment: Hi as you said adding #!/usr/bin/env python on d top app.py fixed the issue.but i dont know whtas exactly happening.Anyway thanks for your help

Comment: If you think this will help others when they have a similar problem, please approve this answer.