# Container is automatically exiting

Tags: docker

Below is my Dockerfile:

```sh
FROM python:3
COPY . /Demo
WORKDIR /Demo
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 9005
CMD python ./app.py
```

I am using following command to run the resulting image:

```
docker run -it -d host:port imagename:v1
```

The container is automatically exiting.  When I run `docker ps`, no running container is shown.

Comment: When you encounter this situation, the easiest first thing to start with is to remove the `docker run -d` option and run the container in the foreground.  Does it print out an informative error message before it exits?

Comment: when I am running container without -d option it is showing me error :- OSError [Errno 8] Exec format error : '/Demo/app.py'                                                      It does not give any informative error message   .....

Comment: use the full path of the python script in the last line with CMD, or something like tihs

```CMD ["python","/full/path/to/app.py"]```

Comment: [Flask CLI throws 'OSError: \[Errno 8\] Exec format error' when run through docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55271912/flask-cli-throws-oserror-errno-8-exec-format-error-when-run-through-docker) might be relevant?  It's hard to tell without having enough code included in the question itself to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this line:

```
CMD python ./app.py
```

give absolute path like below:

```
CMD python /<path-to-script>/app.py
```